# How can I avoid a route collision?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I want to render a `<Product>` when the user visits `/Products/1`.

I want to render a `<CreateProduct>` when the user visits `/Products/new`.

My router looks like so:

```
<Route exact path="/Products/new" component={CreateProduct} />
<Route exact path="/Products/:productId" component={Product} />
```

If the user browses to `/Products/new`, it matches both routes and results in the `Product` component throwing errors re: not finding a product with the id `new`.

I haven't been able to find anything in the react-router documentation to avoid this.  I could potentially use this hack, but there has to be a "better" way:

```
<Route exact path="/Products/new" component={CreateProduct} />
<Route exact path="/Products/:productId" render={renderProduct} />
```

using a function to render the `<Product>` route:

```
const renderProduct = props =>
  props.match.params.productId === 'new'
    ? null
    : <Product {...props} />;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<Switch />`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/Products/new" component={CreateProduct} />
  <Route exact path="/Products/:productId" component={Product} />
</Switch>
```

It will try to find the first match.
So `/Products/new` will match the first route and skip the second.
`/Products/1` will match the second.

Comment: Thats precisely what I needed.  I guess my google foo wasn't quite up to standard.  Will accept when the timer allows it

Comment: You use react-router v4, right? It's easier to understand than the previous versions.

Comment: You may read this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches